# Create ansible list variable with jinja2

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, jinja2

The following code is in the defaults/main.yml file for a role:

```
  file_env: "{% if cf_env is equalto 'cf10_dev' %}\
  dev\
  {% elif cf_env is equalto 'cf10_stg' %}\
  stg\
  {% elif (cf_env is equalto 'cf10_prd') or (cf_env is equalto 'cf10_prd_ext') %}\
  prd\
  {% elif cf_env is equalto 'cf11' %}\
  [dev, prd]
  {% endif %}"
```

The first 3 conditional statements work fine, where the `file_env` var is set to a single value, but when trying to set the `file_env` var to a list (the last elif statement), it doesn't work:

```
failed: [server-new.xxx.com] (item=[dev, prd] ) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "[dev, prd] ", "msg": "Destination /opt/coldfusion11/[dev, prd] 01/bin/jvm.config does not exist !", "rc": 257}
```

Here is the task that generates the above error:

```
- name: Update jvm.config for coldfusion11 server
  lineinfile:
    path: /opt/coldfusion11/{{ item }}01/bin/jvm.config
    regexp: '^java.home'
    line: 'java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-openjdk'
  loop:
    - "{{ file_env }}"
  notify:
    - handler_create_script_list
    - handler_restart_coldfusion10
  when:
    - cf_env == "cf11"
```

How can I set the `file_env` var to a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If your are going to loop over your var, you should always return a list (with single element when needed) to avoid possible tricky errors. You simply need to modify your `loop` expression to the following:

   ```yaml
   loop: "{{ file_env }}"
   ```
2. Your template expressions are not using [white space control](https://tedboy.github.io/jinja2/templ6.html) which will end up with new lines in the output when they should not appear.
3. Your variable definition is hardly readable (and makes me think you have a deeper project architecture issue but that's an other story). Taking into account point 1 above, I suggest you refactor to the following more readable, sustainable and working form using a key/value mapping in a dict and getting the corresponding value in your final var

   ```yaml
   files_by_env
     cf10_dev:
       - dev
     cf10_stg:
       - stg
     cf10_prd:
       - prd
     cf10_prd_ext:
       - prd
     cf11:
      - dev
      - prd

   file_env: "{{ files_by_env[cf_env] }}"
   ```

   Alternatively, you can reverse the definition in the dict (i.e. list environments for every file) which is slightly less verbose but leads to a more complicated expression to get the result

   ```yaml
   env_by_file:
     dev:
       - cf10_dev
       - cf11
     stg:
       - cf10_stg
     prd:
       - cf10_prd
       - cf10_prd_ext
       - cf11

   file_env: "{{ env_by_file | dict2items | selectattr('value', 'contains', cf_env) | map(attribute='key') | list }}"
   ```

Comment: this solution worked spectacularly, thank you and Happy New Year!

Answer (score 3):

I believe your issue is that it's interpreting the variable as a string, literally `'[dev, prd] '` (with a space at the end, judging by the error message).

I think you want to try a different format as suggested in https://serverfault.com/a/913936/512181

Comment: agreed, it is interpreting the variable as a literal string. Thanks for the link, I looked it over and tried modifying my code, and the variable is still treated as a literal string instead of a list. Any other ideas would be appreciated.